# python time to read one file increases with amount of files in the folder

Tags: python, performance

my python script suppose to do the following things:

1) count the files in the folder "output" which is done within like 0.0 seconds

2) read only the first file which is called n0.dat and create an empty list from it

```
import os, csv

icoords, jcoords, kcoords = set(),set(),set()
rowLen = 10 

nMax = len([file for file in os.listdir('output') if file.endswith('.dat')])
print(nMax)

with open('output/n0.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
print ('opened')
    myReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ') 
    for row in myReader:
        if len(row) == rowLen:
            icoords.add(int(row[0])) 
            jcoords.add(int(row[1])) 
            kcoords.add(int(row[2])) 
    iMin, jMin, kMin, iMax, jMax, kMax = min(icoords), min(jcoords), min(kcoords), max(icoords)+1, max(jcoords)+1, max(kcoords)+1
    cV = [[[[[] for n in range(nMax)] for k in range(kMax)] for j in range(jMax)] for i in range(iMax)]
```

The problem is: if I have only one file in the folder, it takes just 2 seconds to finish the program; if I have 20 files it takes 15 seconds and if I have 60 files, I get memory error.

Why? Does python stores all the files, that were counted, somewhere in the computer memory?

Btw. each file is 4.51 MB and they was not changed in the different runs.

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Comment: `nMax` is the number of files, and in your last line you are iterating over `nMax`. So yes, I would expect memory consumption and runtime to grow.

Comment: ahh sure :( thank you!

Comment: Well, time seems to increase only with increasing `nMax`, it doesn't matter if I count the files to get it or set `nMax` manually

Comment: On the side, your method of calculating nMax creates a list and finds its length.  A more memory-efficient method would be to increment a number for each item as you iterate so that you don't need to remember them all. Using parentheses instead of brackets makes it an iterable instead of a list, which means that each value is calculated as it is needed.  The code is like this: `nMax = sum(1 for file in os.listdir('output') if file.endswith('.dat'))`